# Как сделать переход в старую Activity при нажатии на уведомление?

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Использование следующего кода приводит к открытию приложения и созданию **новой** Activity. При этом все внутренние функции запускаются повторно, что в конечном итоге приводит к сбою.

```
Intent nIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
nIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, nIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID) 
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_512)
                                    // ...some other params
                                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Подскажите как реализовать переход из уведомления в уже запущенную Activity. Возможно я что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите `флагIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, а в манифесте к активности `MainActivity` добавьте `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.

Comment: Спасибо, оно работает! Ваше решение куда лучше, поскольку проще и не плодит лишних сущностей. Остаётся надеяться, что launchMode="singleTask" не повлечёт проблем с многозадачностью.

Пойду учить матчасть!

Answer (score 0):

```
nIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Вы здесь и говорите открыть новую activity

исправьте

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplication(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Спасибо, что указали ошибку, но предложенное решение, к сожалению, не помогло. Тем не менее я наткнулся на весьма удачный "костыль", решающий мою проблему (см. ответ ниже).

Comment: Какой-то неправильный костыль. У меня без проблем работает

Comment: Большинство новых устройств требует наличие флага Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, ваше решение работать там не будет.

Comment: Не уверен в вашей правоте. Устройства не влияют на систему

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо David Wasser'у за находчивое решение :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286683

Идея максимально проста - нужно направить запрос не в MainActivity, а в некоторое пустое Activity, которое при открытии мгновенно закроется. Последовательность действий:

1. Создаём новый Java-класс:

---

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        finish();
    }
}
```

2. Объявляем в AndroidManifest.xml:

---

```
<activity android:name=".NotificationActivity" />
```

3. Создаём перенаправление из уведомления:

---

```
Intent nIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), NotificationActivity.class);
nIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
nIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
nIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplication(), 0, nIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_512)                
                //some other params
                .setContentIntent(pIntent);
```